# Uniform convergence of power series with decreasing coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, holomorphic-functions

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a monotone decreasing sequence of real numbers, with limit $0$.

Prove that, for each $0<\delta<2$, the power series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$

converges uniformly on each $\Omega_\delta = \{z : |z|\leq 1 , |z-1|\geq \delta\}$

I have no idea on how to deal with the points in the boundary. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a_n \downarrow 0$ (trivially uniformly with respect to $z$) the Dirichlet test implies uniform convergence when $\left| \sum_{k=1}^n z^k\right|$ is uniformly bounded for all $z \in \Omega_\delta$ and for all $n$.

In this case,

$$\left| \sum_{k=1}^n z^k\right| = \left|\frac{z - z^{n+1}}{1-z} \right| \leqslant \frac{|z|(1+ |z|^n)}{|1-z|} \leqslant \frac{2}{\delta}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I had not heard about Dirichlet test! :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test.  It extends for uniform convergence to a series $\sum a_n(x) b_n(x)$ when $a_n(x) \to 0$ monotonically (decreasing) and uniformly for all $x$ and $\left|\sum_{k \leqslant n} b_k(x)\right|$ is uniformly bounded.  You can also use summation by parts here -- which basically proves the Dirichlet test.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is very well explained there!

Comment: @JaimeArboledaCastilla: You're welcome.